# Error during Building an APK file in Android Studio 3.0.0 MultiDex Error

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, build.gradle, android-multidex

after installation of android environment newely, my old project doesn't work anymore always I have multidex error.

**Error:**

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error converting bytecode to dex:\nCause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/cookie/CookieSpecFactory;","sources":[{}],"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:\ncom.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/cookie/CookieSpecFactory;\n","tool":"Dex"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/cookie/CookieSpecFactory;","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)","sources":[{}]}

FAILED
:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/cookie/CookieSpecFactory;

**My build.gradle file :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
        all*.exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nasri.a8xmovie"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }



    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        lintOptions{
            abortOnError false
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }


    productFlavors {
    }
}

afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
        } else {
            dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven {
        url 'https://raw.github.com/rejasupotaro/AsyncRssClient/master/AsyncRssClient/repository'
    }
    maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/gigamole/maven/' }
    google()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile project(path: ':sAXRSSReader', configuration: 'default')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile project(path: ':breathing-progress', configuration: 'default')
    compile 'rejasupotaro:async-rss-client:0.0.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.uwetrottmann.tmdb2:tmdb-java:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev179-1.22.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.bugsnag:bugsnag-android:3.+'
    compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.14.1'
    compile 'com.github.xiprox.errorview:library:2.+'
    compile 'com.github.sembozdemir:ViewPagerArrowIndicator:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.25.9'
    compile 'com.github.devlight.navigationtabstrip:navigationtabstrip:+'
    compile project(path: ':Downloader', configuration: 'default')
}
```

**AndroidManifest file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nasri.a8xmovie">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME"
            android:value="com.example.nasri.a8xmovie.CastOptionsProvider" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.bugsnag.android.API_KEY"
            android:value="bfca1d3d875" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SMDBIntro"
            android:label=" "
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|uiMode"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.VideoActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.MovieActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.nasri.a8xmovie.activities.MainActivity" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="tech.salroid.com"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MovieDetailActivity"
            android:theme="@style/DetailsActivityThemeDark" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.FullCastActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.CharacterDetailsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.FullMovieActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".FullImageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/MaterialTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.TVShowActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.nasri.a8xmovie.activities.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.TVShowDetailsActivity"
            android:theme="@style/DetailsActivityTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.NewsActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.nasri.a8xmovie.activities.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.FilmStreamingActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.nasri.a8xmovie.activities.MainActivity" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="tech.salroid.com"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.SettingsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.SavedMoviesActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".VideoPlayer"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ExpandedControlsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".VideoPlayer" />
            >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.FullSaisonActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.SaisonDetailsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.FullEpisodeActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.EpisodeDetailsActivity" />
        <!--
 ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
     App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.StreamingActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_streaming"
            android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.StreamingGenreActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.DownloadActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.nasri.a8xmovie.activities.StreamingActivity" />
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".service.DownloadService"></service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Java Application File :**

```
package com.example.nasri.a8xmovie;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;
import android.util.Log;

import com.aspsine.multithreaddownload.DownloadConfiguration;
import com.aspsine.multithreaddownload.DownloadManager;
import com.bugsnag.android.Bugsnag;
import com.example.nasri.a8xmovie.entities.DownloadInfo;
import com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.Fresco;

import java.util.List;

import Utils.DataLists;
import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmConfiguration;


/**
 * Created by nasri on 08/11/16.
 */

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static Context sContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sContext = getApplicationContext();
        Bugsnag.init(this);
        Fresco.initialize(this);
        Realm.init(this);


        initDownloader();
        CrashHandler.getInstance(sContext);
    }

    private void initDownloader() {
        DownloadConfiguration configuration = new DownloadConfiguration();
        configuration.setMaxThreadNum(10);
        configuration.setThreadNum(3);
        DownloadManager.getInstance().init(getApplicationContext(), configuration);
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return sContext;
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

**I tried many solutions, but no solution work with me.**

Comment: did you add   MultiDex.install(this); please provide your manifest. And Application class

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, i edit my question.

Comment: did you try clean and build project or invalidate caches/restart

Comment: yes i do it but the same error

Comment: add  android.enableAapt2=false  in your gradle.properties file. then sync project.. let me know the result.

Comment: always multidex error